# Not able to fetch the key-value from KVM in Apigee using Python Script

Tags: python, apigee

I have created a KVM in Apigee with the name "test_kvm" and the key is "name" with value "myname".
So basically it's like {"name": "myname"} and the value is encrypted. In KVM policy also I am using private prefix `<Get assignTo private.name>...</>`

Now when I am trying to fetch this variable into my python script using PythonScript policy using the script `getname = flow.getVariable("private.name")` this value is getting populated by "None". and not by value "myname".

Why am I getting None and how to properly fetch the Key value from KVM in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the thing is we have to deploy kvm in the same environment that we are using to deploy our api proxy.